# Tick label rotation does not work with log scale?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have the following example code that produces a contour plot with logarithmic scales. I now want to rotate the x-axis labels, since they are overlapping. I found a solution on the internet, but it does not work in my case. I guess it's due to the logarithmic scale?

```
customTicks = 
  Table[{i, Rotate[i, Pi/4]}, {i, {1.*^-5, 5.*^-5, 1.*^-4}}];

ContourPlot[m^2*g^3, {m, 10^(-5), 1*10^(-4)}, {g, 0.01, 0.04}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Log\), \
\(10\)]\)|\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(E\), \
\(^\)], \(2\)], \
\(++\)]\)|[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(^\
\)], \(0\)], \(-+\)]\)]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}], 
 PlotPoints -> 15, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 10, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["m", 24], Style["g", 24]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18], 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{m, g, z}, g <= omV/B0V*nV*10^9*Sqrt[1 - m^2]], 
 Ticks -> {customTicks, Automatic}]
```

The produced figure looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`:

```
ContourPlot[m^2*g^3, {m, 10^(-5), 1*10^(-4)}, {g, 0.01, 0.04}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotPoints -> 15, 
 PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 10, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["m", 24], Style["g", 24]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {customTicks, Automatic}}]
```

[image]